# iOS App Store rejection process

Tags: ios, app-store

My app was just rejected from the App Store. They gave me a reason as to why, and I went ahead and fixed it.

My question is, during their review do they find the first bug, and then reject it and send me the reason why, or do they do a thorough review even after finding the first bug and list all possible reasons of rejection to me?

Comment: No one except Apple have the definitive answer to this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not Apple customer support](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/), and no one else can really answer this (not that they will).

Answer (score 3):

The App Store review process does not follow a specific set of rules. It has [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) that the reviewers follow, but at the end of the day, a lot of it is left to the discretion of the reviewer.

As such, there's no definitive answer to your question. Historically for me, I will get a kickback after the first problem that is found and later builds with those problems fixed have been kickbacked for a different problem that also existed already. This could be because they didn't catch it the first time or once they encountered the first issue, they went ahead and rejected it. There is no official source on this policy.

Answer (score 0):

AppStore review team won't test your app for bugs. They just go through app functionality and check is it satisfy to all guidelines. They can reject app for any reason - wrong UX, not expected behavior, they can even ask you to change some names or titles (it happened to me recently, when I implemented apple pay in my app). It calls `binary rejected`. If some info in app itunes page is wrong, they can make rejection too, it will be `metadata rejected`.
 
Yes, they can reject your app if they find some very critical bug.
For you case, they found the first critical bug and made a rejection. After resubmission, if it will be some other reason for rejection, they can make another reject too.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience App Store Review will stop when thy find a problem, and will then proceed to test other things when you’ve fixed the problem they reported.  That means they may well come back with more issues after you fix the first one.